# Non-Printable Characters on WPF RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, rtf

I want to add non-printable characters to WPF RichTextBox.
For simplicity I'm using Extended WPF Toolkit RichTextBox which provide Text property to directly access RTF source string.

In particular I want to add token at caret poistion with the following syntax: ***ACK** genericString **ACK*** (ACK corresponds to ASCII code 4).

I was able to initialize my RTF in the proper way and the ACK is correctly added, but, when I programatically add a new expressione, previous ACK is striped out from the source string.
The following code shows how I add new expressione at caret position (I tried two methods):

```
//first method 
TextRange tr = new TextRange(rtfControl.CaretPosition, rtfControl.CaretPosition);
tr.Text += "genericString";

//second method
rtfControl.CaretPosition.InsertTextInRun("genericString");
```

I can’t even understand how to proper add the ACK char using the *InsertTextInRun()* function.

```
string stringToAdd = (char)4 + "genericString" + (char)4;
// stringToAdd actually contains ACK
rtfControl.CaretPosition.InsertTextInRun(stringToAdd);
// ACK is not added to RTF string
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? Unprintable characters are by definition .... unprintable. RTF text isn't plain text either and special characters need to be encoded, eg `\'04`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos because, for example, genericString could be "1+2" and using ACK I can scan the string and evaluate the espression printing che result "3"

Comment: So you're trying to turn RTF into LaTeX. The characters you used are invalid in RTF though. RTF isn't a freeform text file. You can't insert arbitrary characters. It *does* support math objects and fields though